# setAutoCommit(false) doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I'm trying to unable the autocommit in some methods in order to make them transactional. I use spring JDBC Template.

I tried to use de @Transactional annotation but another web applications depending from this one stopped working correctly, so I tried something different. I tried to get the connection from the template, and set the autocommit to false manually.

The problem is, I don't think it's disabled at all. I have an insert method, and at the end of it, in order to test, i do a rollback instead of a commit.

In the JUnit test, I try to recover an object with an Id that doesn't exist, it returns nothing. Then I create an object with that Id, and try to insert it. It should return nothing, because the insert method does a rollback, but it returns the object I inserted.

Here is some code.

Data Source bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="${jdbc.jndiName}" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Declaration of Data Source in the DAO that does the insert:

```
  @Autowired
  public final void setDataSource(final DataSource pDataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(pDataSource);
  }
```

Insert method:

```
    public final void insertProcedimiento(final Procedimiento pProcedimiento) throws DataManipulationException, SQLException {
        /**
         * Se obtiene la conexión a partir del DataSource.
         */
        final DataSource ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
        final Connection conexion = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(ds);

        try {
          //Se establece el AutoCommit como false para hacer rollback en caso de que haya algún error al insertar el procedimiento
          conexion.setAutoCommit(false);

          // Instanciación del template de JDBC
          this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);

          // Inicializar el objeto que contendrá los parámetros de la query
          this.namedParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

          final String  query = (
              "INSERT INTO DEX_PROCEDIMIENTO(PRO_CODIGO_INTERNO,PRO_CODIGO_SIA,PRO_TIPO_TRAMITE,PRO_INTERNO,PRO_ES_COMUN,PRO_DENOMINACION,PRO_DESCRIPCION,PRO_OBSERVACIONES,PRO_COD_ORG_RESPONSABLE_N1,"
                  + "PRO_COD_ORG_RESPONSABLE_N2,PRO_UNIDAD_GESTORA_TRAMITE,PRO_COD_ORGANICA,PRO_SUJETO_TASAS,PRO_PERIODICIDAD,PRO_COD_CLASE_TRAMITE,PRO_CLASIFICACION_ARCHIVO,PRO_REQUISITOS_INICIACION,"
                  + "PRO_PRESENCIAL_NO_ADAPTABLE,PRO_COD_NIVEL_AE,PRO_COD_REQUISITOS_IDENT_PJ,PRO_COD_REQUISITOS_IDENT_PF,PRO_ID_INTEGRADO_CLAVE,PRO_OBS_INTEGRADO_CLAVE,PRO_ENLACE_WEB,PRO_PORTAL,"
                  + "PRO_FORMA_INI_INTERESADO,PRO_COD_SILENCIO_INTERESADO,PRO_FORMA_INI_OFICIO,PRO_COD_SILENCIO_OFICIO,PRO_NUMERO_PLAZO_RESOLUCION,PRO_COD_TIPO_PLAZO_RESOLUCION,PRO_FIN_VIA,PRO_PROCEDIMIENTO_AUTORIZACION,"
                  + "PRO_RESPONSABLE,PRO_VISIBLE_CIUDADANO,PRO_FECHA_VISIBLE_CIUDADANO,PRO_RESPONSABLE_TECNICO,PRO_FECHA_ALTA,PRO_FECHA_MODIFICACION,PRO_USUARIO_MODIFICACION,PRO_ESTADO)"
                  + "VALUES(:iProCodigoInterno, :iProCodigoSia, :sProTipoTramite, :sProInterno,  :sProEsComun, :sProDenominacion, :sProDescripcion, :sProObservaciones, :sProCodOrgResponsableN1, :sProCodOrgResponsableN2, "
                  + ":sProUnidadGestoraTramite, :iProCodOrganica, :sProSujetoTasas, :iProPeriodicidad, :iProCodClaseTramite, :sProClasificacionArchivo, :sProRequisitosIniciacion, :sProPresencialNoAdaptable, :iProCodNivelAe, "
                  + ":sProCodRequisitosIdenPj, :sProCodRequisitosIdenPf, :sProIdIntegradoClave, :sProObsIntegracionClave, :sProEnlaceWeb, :iProPortal, :sProFormaIniInteresado, :iProCodSilencioInteresado, :sProFormaIniOficio, "
                  + ":iProCodSilencioOficio, :iProNumeroPlazoResolucion, :iProCodTipoPlazoResolucion, :sProFinVia, :iProProcedimientoAutorizacion, :sProResponsable, :sProVisibleCiudadano, :dProFechaVisibleCiudadano, "
                  + ":sProResponsableTecnico, :dProFechaAlta, :dProFechaModificacion, :sProUsuarioModificacion, :sProEstado)");

          namedParameters.put("iProCodigoInterno", pProcedimiento.getProCodigoInterno());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodigoSia", pProcedimiento.getProCodigoSia());
          namedParameters.put("sProTipoTramite", pProcedimiento.getProTipoTramite());
          namedParameters.put("sProInterno", pProcedimiento.getProInterno());
          namedParameters.put("sProEsComun", pProcedimiento.getProEsComun());
          namedParameters.put("sProDenominacion", pProcedimiento.getProDenominacion());
          namedParameters.put("sProDescripcion", pProcedimiento.getProDescripcion());
          namedParameters.put("sProObservaciones", pProcedimiento.getProObservaciones());
          namedParameters.put("sProCodOrgResponsableN1", pProcedimiento.getProCodOrgResponsableN1());
          namedParameters.put("sProCodOrgResponsableN2", pProcedimiento.getProCodOrgResponsableN2());
          namedParameters.put("sProUnidadGestoraTramite", pProcedimiento.getProUnidadGestoraTramite());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodOrganica", pProcedimiento.getProCodOrganica());
          namedParameters.put("sProSujetoTasas", pProcedimiento.getProSujetoTasas());
          namedParameters.put("iProPeriodicidad", pProcedimiento.getProPeriodicidad());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodClaseTramite", pProcedimiento.getProCodClaseTramite());
          namedParameters.put("sProClasificacionArchivo", pProcedimiento.getProClasificacionArchivo());
          namedParameters.put("sProRequisitosIniciacion", pProcedimiento.getProRequisitosIniciacion());
          namedParameters.put("sProPresencialNoAdaptable", pProcedimiento.getProPresencialNoAdaptable());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodNivelAe", pProcedimiento.getProCodNivelAe());
          namedParameters.put("sProCodRequisitosIdenPj", pProcedimiento.getProCodRequisitosIdenPj());
          namedParameters.put("sProCodRequisitosIdenPf", pProcedimiento.getProCodRequisitosIdenPf());
          namedParameters.put("sProIdIntegradoClave", pProcedimiento.getProIdIntegradoClave());
          namedParameters.put("sProObsIntegracionClave", pProcedimiento.getProObsIntegracionClave());
          namedParameters.put("sProEnlaceWeb", pProcedimiento.getProEnlaceWeb());
          namedParameters.put("iProPortal", pProcedimiento.getProPortal());
          namedParameters.put("sProFormaIniInteresado", pProcedimiento.getProFormaIniInteresado());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodSilencioInteresado", pProcedimiento.getProCodSilencioInteresado());
          namedParameters.put("sProFormaIniOficio", pProcedimiento.getProFormaIniOficio());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodSilencioOficio", pProcedimiento.getProCodSilencioOficio());
          namedParameters.put("iProNumeroPlazoResolucion", pProcedimiento.getProNumeroPlazoResolucion());
          namedParameters.put("iProCodTipoPlazoResolucion", pProcedimiento.getProCodTipoPlazoResolucion());
          namedParameters.put("sProFinVia", pProcedimiento.getProFinVia());
          namedParameters.put("iProProcedimientoAutorizacion", pProcedimiento.getProProcedimientoAutorizacion());
          namedParameters.put("sProResponsable", pProcedimiento.getProResponsable());
          namedParameters.put("sProVisibleCiudadano", pProcedimiento.getProVisibleCiudadano());
          namedParameters.put("dProFechaVisibleCiudadano", pProcedimiento.getProFechaVisibleCiudadano());
          namedParameters.put("sProResponsableTecnico", pProcedimiento.getProResponsableTecnico());
          namedParameters.put("dProFechaAlta", pProcedimiento.getProFechaAlta());
          namedParameters.put("dProFechaModificacion", pProcedimiento.getProFechaModificacion());
          namedParameters.put("sProUsuarioModificacion", pProcedimiento.getProUsuarioModificacion());
          namedParameters.put("sProEstado", pProcedimiento.getProEstado());

          // Mapear los parámetros de la query almacenados en el HashMap
          final SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource(namedParameters);

          // Ejecutar la query y lanzar excepción en caso de fallo
          try {
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, params);
          } catch (final DataAccessException exDA) {
            LOGGER.error("Error al insertar procedimiento: " + exDA.getMessage());
            throw new DataManipulationException("Error al insertar procedimiento: " + exDA.getMessage());
          }

          //Here I should do the conexion.commit()
          conexion.rollback();

        } catch (SQLException | DataManipulationException e) {
          //Se hace el rollback de los cambios
          conexion.rollback();
        }
      }
```

Why isn't the autocommit(false) working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to here? Could be that the driver implementation doesn't support transactions correctly (or the backend just doesn't support transactions). Not that that either of those is super likely, still you should probably put that in there.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are not *using* the connection that you called `setAutoCommit(false)` on. Instead, you are creating a new JdbcTemplate with a DataSource, and that JdbcTemplate will just get a new connection from the DataSource.

Comment: You shouldn't be even doing that. You should be using proper transaction management. Hence figure out why `@Transactional` isn't working and fix that. If you really want to work around it wrap the code in a `TransactionTemplate` but don't start messing around with plain JDBC when using `JdcbTemplate`. Also your code is quite dangerous as you are (re)setting instance variables, now imagine multiple requests calling this method at the same time...

Comment: My intention is to make @Transactional work, but at this moment I don't have the time to find out why isn't it working. I'll try the TransactionTemplate workaround for now, thanks!

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Is there any way to get the actual connection?

Comment: Where is conexion.commit()?, conexion.setAutoCommit(false) is grouping all the statement until it finds to conexion.commit() then, in this moment, is when it execute all the queries, if there is not error